# Ferramenta de design que exporta para .xib ou .storyboard

Tags: ios, mobile, xib, storyboard

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta que pode ser usada para desenvolver o design do app (como o programa Prototyper da Justinmind ) e depois exportar para o formato xib ou storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

não acho que existe, e não vejo nenhuma razão de existir algo desse tipo. O storyboard não é uma ferramenta de design como photoshop, ou uma extensão como jpg. Ele faz parte de uma arquitetura chamada MVC.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html

O XIB/Storyboard como a "VIEW" do MVC, possui várias responsabilidades como: criar vínculo entre view e controller, oferecer formas de deixar a sua view adaptavel a portrait e landscape usando Auto Layout, vc pode inserir coisas na sua view através de código, e no XCode 6, vc possui apenas 1 storyboard para phone, tablet e desktop.
Montar a view da sua aplicação não é algo que pode ser gerado, deve ser desenvolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Que converte não tem, mas tem o [Sympli](https://sympli.io) que ajuda a criar o layout do Sketch para o xcode